# Function clock() in C

Tags: c, unix, system-calls, time.h

While studying the clock () function located in time.h, I asked myself the question of making a simple program to see how it worked. I was surprised when running this program the result shown is 0, while what I expected was 2. Where am I wrong?

```
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){
  int msec = 0;
  clock_t before = clock();
  sleep(2);
  clock_t difference = clock() - before;
  msec = difference * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
  printf("Time taken %d seconds\n",msec/1000);
}
```

Comment: I suggest `double msec = difference * 1000.0 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;` and print a `double`.

Comment: From [man page](https://linux.die.net/man/3/clock): _"If the processor time used is not available or its value cannot be represented, the function returns the value (clock_t) -1."_ Might it bewhat is happening to you, in both `clock ()` calls, so that you have `-1-(-1)=0`?

Comment: @WeatherVane Does this order is better than divide then multiply? I've read somewhere that doubles lose precision if they are far from `0..abs(1)` range.

Comment: @yvw when I ran it with the MS function `Sleep(2000)` it reported `1` but when using `double` it reported `1.999999`. Also the MS implementation of `clock()` is non-conforming in that it measures wall time.

Comment: @WeatherVane As you say. Do the order of calculation makes a difference here?

Comment: @yvw in the *general* case, the integer multiplication can overflow. And here, OP multiplies by 1000 and then divides by 1000. Even when going directly to seconds with `difference / CLOCKS_PER_SEC` the integer division will lose any fractional part.

Comment: @WeatherVane And `double`? Do double lose precision?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`clock` measures processor time used by your program. Your program does not use processor time while it is sleeping. The rest of your program uses less than a millisecond of time.

To measure “wall clock” or “real world” time, use `time`, and use `difftime` to subtract to `time_t` values, the type returned by `time`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(int argc, const char *argv[])
{
    time_t before = time(NULL);
    sleep(2);
    double difference = difftime(time(NULL), before);
    printf("The time taken was %g seconds.\n", difference);
}
```